# Split ROWS into multiple COLUMN

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have some information on student name and their roll no -
[image]

And I want to split them into 3 sets of column like below. The total no of rows should always be ceiling value of (# of rows/3)
[image]

Comment: SQL tables have no order.  So, there is no way to control the ordering of the results.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so which values end up where is arbitrary:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then name end) as name_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then roll end) as roll_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then name end) as name_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then roll end) as roll_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then name end) as name_3,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then roll end) as roll_3       
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor(seqnum / 3);
```

If you have an ordering column, then use it instead of `(select null)`.